# textarea auto height js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как добиться изменения `height` `textarea` на `auto` в зависимости от контента. При нажатии на open должен быть виден весь текст, который находиться в `textarea`. Спасибо.

```js
function description_task() {
 var open = document.getElementById('description_task').getAttribute('data-open');
 if (open == 1) {
  document.getElementById('description_task').style.height = 'auto';
  document.getElementById('description_task').setAttribute('data-open', 2);
 } else {
  document.getElementById('description_task').style.height = '22px';
  document.getElementById('description_task').setAttribute('data-open', 1);
 }
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 95%;
  height: 22px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: justify;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
}

span {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  color: #007bff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea data-open="1" id="description_task" placeholder="Описание задачи">Петербург, лето 1805 г. На вечере у фрейлины Шерер присутствуют среди прочих гостей Пьер Безухов, незаконный сын богатого вельможи, и князь Андрей Болконский. Разговор заходит о Наполеоне, и оба друга пытаются защитить великого человека от осуждений хозяйки вечера и её гостей. Князь Андрей собирается на войну, потому что мечтает о славе, равной славе Наполеона, а Пьер не знает, чем ему заняться, участвует в кутежах петербургской молодёжи (здесь особое место занимает Федор Долохов, бедный, но чрезвычайно волевой и решительный офицер); за очередное озорство Пьер выслан из столицы, а Долохов разжалован в солдаты.
</textarea>
<span id="description_icon_task" onclick="description_task()" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Развернуть описание">Open</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите [это решение](https://jsfiddle.net/8m6vb2f0/). Идея в том, чтобы держать скрытый div, в который будет дублироваться текст из textarea и при необходимости высота div будет применяться к textarea.

В вашем случае это будет как-то так:

```js
function description_task() {
  var open = document.getElementById('description_task').getAttribute('data-open');
  if (open == 1) {

  var min_line_height = '22px';
  var obj = document.getElementById('description_task');
  var div = document.getElementById('description_task_div');
  div.innerHTML = obj.value;
  var obj_height = div.offsetHeight;
  if (event.keyCode == 13)
    obj_height += line_height;
  else if (obj_height < min_line_height)
    obj_height = min_line_height;
  obj.style.height = obj_height + 'px';


    document.getElementById('description_task').setAttribute('data-open', 2);
  } else {
    document.getElementById('description_task').style.height = '22px';
    document.getElementById('description_task').setAttribute('data-open', 1);
  }
}
```

```css
  textarea {
  width: 95%;
  height: 22px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: justify;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
  #description_task_div{
  width: 95%;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  visibility:hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  }

span {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  color: #007bff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea data-open="1" id="description_task" placeholder="Описание задачи">Петербург, лето 1805 г. На вечере у фрейлины Шерер присутствуют среди прочих гостей Пьер Безухов, незаконный сын богатого вельможи, и князь Андрей Болконский. Разговор заходит о Наполеоне, и оба друга пытаются защитить великого человека от осуждений хозяйки вечера и её гостей. Князь Андрей собирается на войну, потому что мечтает о славе, равной славе Наполеона, а Пьер не знает, чем ему заняться, участвует в кутежах петербургской молодёжи (здесь особое место занимает Федор Долохов, бедный, но чрезвычайно волевой и решительный офицер); за очередное озорство Пьер выслан из столицы, а Долохов разжалован в солдаты.
</textarea>
<span id="description_icon_task" onclick="description_task()" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Развернуть описание">Open
</span>

<div id=description_task_div></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, хорошая идея.